# Database changes after App is in store

Tags: iphone, core-data

Folks,

I just have a quick question about updating my app after it is in the store. If I want to add an attribute to an entity in Core Data would I have to create some sort of conversion process.

Regards,
Stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are talking about Core Data. Have a look at the model versioning guidelines: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Yes, I meant Core Data, I've reworded the question accordingly. Reviewing link now...